# using a try statement in write queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have about 40 linq-to-sql queries and I got in the habit of wrapping the write statement around a `catch-try`; something like this:

```
using (MyDC TheDC = new MyDC ())
{
   SomeTable TheTableInDB = new SomeTable();
   ... populate record

   try
   {
      TheDC.SomeTables.InsertOnSubmit(TheTableInDB);
      TheDC.SubmitChanges();
   }... catch...{...}
}
```

Is a try statement in this context a bit unnecessary or is it possible that database operations on a write can fail?

Comment: Anything that involves a network can always fail.  The important question is, how do you want to handle failures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database writes can fail for all manner of reason, not just because of data integrity problems (e.g you tried to write a duplicate value into a column with a `UNIQUE` constraint, but also because the connection can fail due to networking issues, or the server being down, or indeed many other possible causes which are both beyond the control of your code AND entirely unforseeable at the point when you make your calls.

As to whether or not to catch these exceptions, the answer,  as with many things, is "it depends".

- If you can do something *meaningful* in the case of an exception (example: you can identify a connection error and retry the operation because in your specific scenario that is OK) then by all means you should catch those *specific* exceptions that indicate the conditions that you can recover from.
- However, if the exception indicates a problem which you can't (or don't want to) recover from, you shouldn't catch; in general the rule of thumb is

> Don't catch exceptions you can't or won't handle

So whilst this is OK:

```
try
{
   //something
}
catch(SqlException sqlEx)
{
    //check sqlEX to see if you can recover, retry, fail gracefully, etc, 
    //or if you really have to give up and then
    throw; //only if you need to pass it on up
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for information on how to identify if you can retry the operation, and identify more details from the SQL error, etc.

This is pointless:

```
try
{
   //something
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw; //would have been thrown up the call stack anyway,
    //and it's easy to accidentally write
    throw ex; //which loses important call stack information from the original exception

}
```

and of course this

```
try
{
  //something
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
```

is just asking for trouble because you'll never be told that something went wrong!

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input. Decided to keep the try statement in case someone else who joins the project mistakenly creates a bug.

Comment: @frenchie - that's grand, but is there actually anything in that `catch` block? If not, I'd nearly take it out and let your code "fail fast", which will help your testing because you won't miss these errors.